# I cannot type certain special characters in the snippet editor

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, keyboard, mac

When using the snippet editor, I cannot type the following characters:

- `:` (deletes the next word instead)
- `=` (moves cursor forward a word instead)

I assume this is because the snippet editor uses shortcuts on the `⌥` key. I type `:` via `⌥d` and `=` via `⌥f` (this is the [Neo Layout](https://neo-layout.org/) on macOS). On macOS, the `⌥` key always has been a key for accessing different keyboard layers and should never be used without a second modifier key for shortcuts, because that prevents one from writing the symbols that are accessed via this key combination.

The solution would be to map those shortcuts to another combination, at least on macOS.